# Proof that subset is open in $\Bbb R^2$ with coefficients in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: general-topology, open-map

Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Let $B$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the points $(x,y)$ for which $(x,y,x+y)\in A$.
I am struggling a bit how to show that $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
I know that if $B$ is open in $A$ iff $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if they were the same dimension but now I am struggling how to combine the 2D situation and the 3D. My main problem visualising is that I see that $x$ and $y$ come from an open set but how do I know $x+y$ does not pass the boundary of that set? And still I don't see how to combine the dimensions.

Comment: How can $x$, $y$, and $x+y$ be elements of $A$? They are real numbers, elements of $\mathbb R$, not elements of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes my wording was very wrong, I made the mistake of trying to visualize something in metrics while the whole point of topology obviously is linking these different dimensional spaces with homeomorphism maps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to say $B=\{(x,y): (x,y,x+y) \in A\}$.

$f(x,y)=(x,y,x+y)$ defines  a continuous function from $\mathbb R^{2}$ to $\mathbb R^{3}$ and so the inverse image of $A$ under this function is open.

Comment: Of course thanks! I was visualizing instead of thinking about the theorems between the Euclidian spaces, that was my mistake

Comment: I think you misread the question. The condition is "$x$, $y$ and $x+y$ in $A$," not $(x,y,x+y)$ in $A$.

Comment: @bof how is $B \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ in that case?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I guess $B=\emptyset$. The point is that we are supposedly creating a repository of good questions and answers. If a question is badly stated we should first get the OP to fix the question, instead of ignoring the nonsense, answering the "intended" question, and leaving it like that. At the very least, correct the question in the answer: "What you asked makes no sense because . . ., I think you meant to ask . . ."

Answer (score 0):

So $A \subseteq \Bbb R^3$ is given.

You define $B = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: (x,y,x+y) \in A\}= f^{-1}[A]$ where

$$f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3, f(x,y):= (x,y, x+y)$$ It's quite easy to see that $f$ is continuous (it's even a linear map) and so $A$ open implies that $B$ is open by continuity. But taking $A = f[\Bbb R^2]$ we have that $A$ need not be open even when $B$ is.